# How should I mould the output of YOLOv5 model to fit into loss_fn?

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor, yolov5

I am building a Distracted Driver Detection algorithm using YOLOv5. Using dataset from State Farm's Kaggle Competition, I have compiled the dataset to be in the following format:

```
test
├── c0
├── ├── img_100050.jpg
├── ├── img_1005.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c1
├── ├── img_100153.jpg
├── ├── img_100358.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c2
├── ├── img_100029.jpg
├── ├── img_100246.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c3
├── ├── img_100423.jpg
├── ├── img_100503.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c4
├── ├── img_100343.jpg
├── ├── img_100561.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c5
├── ├── img_100121.jpg
├── ├── img_100556.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c6
├── ├── img_100036.jpg
├── ├── img_100200.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c7
├── ├── img_100314.jpg
├── ├── img_100352.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c8
├── ├── img_100295.jpg
├── ├── img_100368.jpg
├── ├── ...
├── c9
├── └── img_100429.jpg
├── └── img_101221.jpg
├── └── ...
train
└── c0
└── ├── img_100026.jpg
└── ├── img_10003.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c1
└── ├── img_100021.jpg
└── ├── img_100045.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c2
└── ├── img_100108.jpg
└── ├── img_100113.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c3
└── ├── img_100006.jpg
└── ├── img_100041.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c4
└── ├── img_100225.jpg
└── ├── img_10025.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c5
└── ├── img_10000.jpg
└── ├── img_100027.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c6
└── ├── img_0.jpg
└── ├── img_100065.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c7
└── ├── img_100057.jpg
└── ├── img_100076.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c8
└── ├── img_100015.jpg
└── ├── img_100235.jpg
└── ├── ...
└── c9
└── └── img_100090.jpg
└── └── img_100100.jpg
└── └── ...
```

Below is my block of code:

```
import os
import torch
import random
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision.io import read_image
from torchvision.io.image import ImageReadMode
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Tuple, Dict, List
from torchinfo import summary

#GLOBAL DEFINITIONS#

test_dir = Path("fypv1/Dataset/test")
train_dir = Path("fypv1/Dataset/train")

print(train_dir)
print(test_dir)

transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(),  # Convert images to grayscale
        transforms.CenterCrop(480),
        transforms.Resize(size=(256, 256)),
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])

def display_random_images(dataset: torch.utils.data.dataset.Dataset,
                          classes: List[str] = None,
                          n: int = 10,
                          display_shape: bool = True,
                          seed: int = None):
    
    # 2. Adjust display if n too high
    if n > 10:
        n = 10
        display_shape = False
        print(f"For display purposes, n shouldn't be larger than 10, setting to 10 and removing shape display.")
    
    # 3. Set random seed
    if seed:
        random.seed(seed)

    # 4. Get random sample indexes
    random_samples_idx = random.sample(range(len(dataset)), k=n)

    # 5. Setup plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

    # 6. Loop through samples and display random samples 
    for i, targ_sample in enumerate(random_samples_idx):
        targ_image, targ_label = dataset[targ_sample][0], dataset[targ_sample][1]

        # 7. Adjust image tensor shape for plotting: [color_channels, height, width] -> [color_channels, height, width]
        targ_image_adjust = targ_image.permute(1, 2, 0)

        # Plot adjusted samples
        plt.subplot(1, n, i+1)
        plt.imshow(targ_image_adjust, cmap='gray')
        plt.axis("off")
        if classes:
            title = f"class: {classes[targ_label]}"
            if display_shape:
                title = title + f"\nshape: {targ_image_adjust.shape}"
        plt.title(title)
    plt.show()    

def test_step(model: torch.nn.Module, dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, loss_fn: torch.nn.Module):
    # Put model in eval mode
    model.eval() 
    
    # Setup test loss and test accuracy values
    test_loss, test_acc = 0, 0
    
    # Turn on inference context manager
    with torch.inference_mode():
        # Loop through DataLoader batches
        for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):    
            # 1. Forward pass
            test_pred_logits = model(X)

            # 2. Calculate and accumulate loss
            loss = loss_fn(test_pred_logits, y)
            test_loss += loss.item()
            
            # Calculate and accumulate accuracy
            test_pred_labels = test_pred_logits.argmax(dim=1)
            test_acc += ((test_pred_labels == y).sum().item()/len(test_pred_labels))
            
    # Adjust metrics to get average loss and accuracy per batch 
    test_loss = test_loss / len(dataloader)
    test_acc = test_acc / len(dataloader)
    return test_loss, test_acc

def train_step(model: torch.nn.Module, dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, loss_fn: torch.nn.Module, optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer):
    # Put model in train mode
    model.train()
    
    # Setup train loss and train accuracy values
    train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
    
    # Loop through data loader data batches
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # 1. Forward pass
        y_pred = model(X)

        # 2. Calculate  and accumulate loss
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        train_loss += loss.item() 

        # 3. Optimizer zero grad
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # 4. Loss backward
        loss.backward()

        # 5. Optimizer step
        optimizer.step()

        # Calculate and accumulate accuracy metric across all batches
        y_pred_class = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(y_pred, dim=1), dim=1)
        train_acc += (y_pred_class == y).sum().item()/len(y_pred)

    # Adjust metrics to get average loss and accuracy per batch 
    train_loss = train_loss / len(dataloader)
    train_acc = train_acc / len(dataloader)
    return train_loss, train_acc

# 1. Take in various parameters required for training and test steps
def train(model: torch.nn.Module, 
          train_dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, 
          test_dataloader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader, 
          optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
          loss_fn: torch.nn.Module = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(),
          epochs: int = 5):
    
    # 2. Create empty results dictionary
    results = {"train_loss": [],
        "train_acc": [],
        "test_loss": [],
        "test_acc": []
    }
    
    # 3. Loop through training and testing steps for a number of epochs
    for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
        train_loss, train_acc = train_step(model=model,
                                           dataloader=train_dataloader,
                                           loss_fn=loss_fn,
                                           optimizer=optimizer)
        test_loss, test_acc = test_step(model=model,
            dataloader=test_dataloader,
            loss_fn=loss_fn)
        
        # 4. Print out what's happening
        print(
            f"Epoch: {epoch+1} | "
            f"train_loss: {train_loss:.4f} | "
            f"train_acc: {train_acc:.4f} | "
            f"test_loss: {test_loss:.4f} | "
            f"test_acc: {test_acc:.4f}"
        )

        # 5. Update results dictionary
        results["train_loss"].append(train_loss)
        results["train_acc"].append(train_acc)
        results["test_loss"].append(test_loss)
        results["test_acc"].append(test_acc)

    # 6. Return the filled results at the end of the epochs
    return results

#IMPORT DATASET#

train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=train_dir, # target folder of images
                                  transform=transform, # transforms to perform on data (images)
                                  target_transform=None) # transforms to perform on labels (if necessary)

test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=test_dir, 
                                 transform=transform)

print(f"Train data:\n{train_data}\nTest data:\n{test_data}")

class_names = train_data.classes
print(train_data.classes)
print (train_data.class_to_idx)
print(len(train_data), len(test_data))

img, label = train_data[0][0], train_data[0][1]
print(f"Image tensor:\n{img}")
print(f"Image shape: {img.shape}")
print(f"Image datatype: {img.dtype}")
print(f"Image label: {label}")
print(f"Label datatype: {type(label)}")

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, 
                              batch_size=1, # how many samples per batch?
                              num_workers=1, # how many subprocesses to use for data loading? (higher = more)
                              shuffle=True) # shuffle the data?

test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_data, 
                             batch_size=1, 
                             num_workers=1, 
                             shuffle=False) # don't usually need to shuffle testing data

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=False, channels=1, classes=10)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
num_epochs = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Start Training
    from timeit import default_timer as timer 
    start_time = timer()

    # Train model
    outputs = train(model=model, 
                            train_dataloader=train_loader,
                            test_dataloader=test_loader,
                            optimizer=optimizer,
                            loss_fn=loss_fn, 
                            epochs=num_epochs)

    # End the timer and print out how long it took
    end_time = timer()
    print(f"Total training time: {end_time-start_time:.3f} seconds")

    #Display Graph
    def plot_loss_curves(results: Dict[str, List[float]]):
        """Plots training curves of a results dictionary.

        Args:
            results (dict): dictionary containing list of values, e.g.
                {"train_loss": [...],
                "train_acc": [...],
                "test_loss": [...],
                "test_acc": [...]}
        """
        
        # Get the loss values of the results dictionary (training and test)
        loss = results['train_loss']
        test_loss = results['test_loss']

        # Get the accuracy values of the results dictionary (training and test)
        accuracy = results['train_acc']
        test_accuracy = results['test_acc']

        # Figure out how many epochs there were
        epochs = range(len(results['train_loss']))

        # Setup a plot 
        plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))

        # Plot loss
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        plt.plot(epochs, loss, label='train_loss')
        plt.plot(epochs, test_loss, label='test_loss')
        plt.title('Loss')
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.legend()

        # Plot accuracy
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        plt.plot(epochs, accuracy, label='train_accuracy')
        plt.plot(epochs, test_accuracy, label='test_accuracy')
        plt.title('Accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('Epochs')
        plt.legend()

        # Display plot
        plt.show()

    plot_loss_curves(outputs)
```

At the line `loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)` in `train_step()`, this error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 226, in <module>
    outputs = train(model=model,
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 153, in train
    train_loss, train_acc = train_step(model=model,
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 115, in train_step
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
  File "D:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\fypv1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl        
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\fypv1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1174, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "D:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\fypv1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list
```

Obviously, the `y_pred` which was the output of the model for YOLOv5 (by ultralytics), returns a list of Tensor, whereas the required format for `loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)` is both Tensors.

I have tried to change the format of the output to Tensor by using `loss = loss_fn(torch.Tensor(y_pred),y)`. However, another error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 226, in <module>
    outputs = train(model=model,
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 153, in train
    train_loss, train_acc = train_step(model=model,
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 115, in train_step
    loss = loss_fn(torch.Tensor(y_pred), y)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

As the output returns a list of Tensor of size 3, I've also tried `loss = loss_fn(y_pred[i],y)`, where i=0,1,2. All of the trials returned an error which is largely similar to the following (taken i=1 as example):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 226, in <module>
    outputs = train(model=model,
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 153, in train
    train_loss, train_acc = train_step(model=model,
  File "d:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\main2.py", line 115, in train_step
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred[1], y)
  File "D:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\fypv1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl        
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\fypv1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1174, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "D:\XMUM Academics\Final Year Project\Project_File\fypv1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: Expected target size [1, 16, 16, 15], got [1]
```

I'm actually lost here. I've searched the whole internet looking for solutions to the abovementioned issue to no avail. How could I pass the output to the loss function as a tensor?

p.s. this is part of my FYP, and is my first time using YOLOv5. Due to the proposal, I cannot change my model to any other, more suitable models. Any help are appreciated.

TL;DR: Tried:

```
loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y) #TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list
loss = loss_fn(torch.Tensor(y_pred),y) #ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
loss = loss_fn(y_pred[i],y) #RuntimeError: Expected target size [1, 16, 16, 15], got [1]
```

loss_fn() requires both tensors in same size.